# ERROR: Could not connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

This is my **dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y git

RUN mkdir api 

WORKDIR ./api

RUN git clone --branch develop https://link

WORKDIR ./api/api/


RUN apt-get install -y docker.io
RUN apt-get -y install curl


RUN curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.22.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)"  -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
RUN mv /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose



RUN docker-compose up
```

I want to docker-compose up inside **docker image**. However,

It gives **ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?** and 
**If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable**

How can I solve this problem I **searched** but none of them worked?

Comment: Are you trying to run a docker-compose installation inside of a docker container? I dont know, if this could work - why are you trying this in the first place?

Comment: I found this page: https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/
Seems like your container has to use some more privileges than a normal docker container. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest rethinking the entire approach of this Dockerfile: you can't run the Docker daemon in a Dockerfile and you can't start any sort of background process.  A shell script that runs on the host might be a better match.

Running any sort of daemon inside a Dockerfile mostly doesn't work; at the end of each `RUN` instruction all running processes are terminated.  Creating a Docker image doesn't preserve any running processes, just the final filesystem and metadata like the default `CMD` to run when you start a container.  So even if `docker-compose up` worked, the results of that wouldn't be persisted in your image.

Running a Docker daemon inside a Docker container is difficult and generally discouraged.  (Sharing the host's Docker socket has significant security implications but is the preferred approach.)  Either way requires some additional permissions, that again just aren't available inside a Dockerfile.

The other red flag for me here is the `RUN git clone` line.  Because of Docker's layer caching, it will be happy to say "oh, I've already `RUN git clone` so I don't need to repeat that step" and you won't wind up with current code.  Feeding credentials for remote git repositories into a Dockerfile is also tricky.  I'd also recommend running source control commands exclusively on the host and not a Dockerfile.

The standard approach here would be to commit a `docker-compose.yml` file to the top of your repository, and run `git clone` and `docker-compose up` directly from the host.  You can't use a Dockerfile as a general-purpose automation tool.